Can we use shadcn ui in chrome extension development?
I want to create a Chrome extension using ShadCN UI, but I'm unsure if it's feasible since I haven't seen any projects using this UI for extensions. Could you confirm if it's possible?
Try to build chrome extension with shadcn ui

Yes, it is possible to use shadcn/ui for a chrome extension, as long as you're using react and tailwind. Simply add the dependency.
There is a repository that already gives you a simple hello world extension using react which you can base your extension off of. https://github.com/Harshita-mindfire/react-chrome-extension (disclaimer: i do not know this repository, i found it after a quick google search)
